# Creating sparse matrix from a list of sparse vectors

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a list of sparse vectors (in R). I need to convert this list to a sparse matrix.
Doing it via a for-loop takes a long time.

```
sm<-spMatrix(length(tc2),n.col)
for(i in 1:length(tc2)){
    sm[i,]<-(tc2[i])[[1]];  
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I can answer, but some more guidance is necessary.  Are these vectors stored in any kind of sparse format?  E.g. are you storing `tc2[[1]]` as a numeric vector with a lot of 0s, or do you use a sparse matrix to represent each vector?  Can you give an example of the data to work with?

Comment: @DAF -- Did my answer address what you were asking? If so, you can accept it by clicking the check mark to its left. If not, can you add an example of the type of sparse vectors that you are wanting to combine in a sparse matrix? Cheers.

Comment: @iterator - I can take a step back, and start with a list of 'itemset', i.e. each entry is a list of numbers, indicating items/words occurring in the row. I'd like to have a sparse matrix representation of this data. Josh's solution works for small examples, but on a sample with 10K rows and 10k items I run out of memory (16 G)

Comment: @DAF -- If I had that data, I'd probably set it up for input to the `sparseMatrix()` constructor function. You'll need three vectors (possibly organized as the columns of a data frame), that represent the row index, column index, and value of each entry.  Run this toy example to see how it works, and then let me know how this goes: `sparseMatrix(i=1:4, j=4:1, x=c(2,4,5,9))`.  Good luck!

Comment: @Josh - thanks! This seems like the most effective solution. I posted a function below that does this.

Comment: Great. I thought that would work. Cheers. Thanks also for posting the solution that did work.

Comment: is there any way to do this in python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a two step solution:

- Use `lapply()` and `as(..., "sparseMatrix")` to convert the list of **sparseVectors** to a list of one column **sparseMatrices**.
- Use `do.call()` and `cBind()` to combine the **sparseMatrices** in a single **sparseMatrix**.

---

```
require(Matrix)

# Create a list of sparseVectors
ss <- as(c(0,0,3, 3.2, 0,0,0,-3), "sparseVector")
l <- replicate(3, ss)

# Combine the sparseVectors into a single sparseMatrix
l <- lapply(l, as, "sparseMatrix")
do.call(cBind, l)

# 8 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                    
# [1,]  .    .    .  
# [2,]  .    .    .  
# [3,]  3.0  3.0  3.0
# [4,]  3.2  3.2  3.2
# [5,]  .    .    .  
# [6,]  .    .    .  
# [7,]  .    .    .  
# [8,] -3.0 -3.0 -3.0
```

Comment: Thanks! This works on the example and does what I want (except I use rBind in do.call since I have rows in the list). However, on text data (10K rows and up to 10K features, though very sparse), do.call hangs R for a very long time so I end up killing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why that's running slow. It looks like `rBind` may actually recursively call `rbind2` (which binds together two rows at a time). That **would** get very slow with large numbers of vectors to rbind together. But as I've suggested an alternative approach to constructing the matrix you really want, I'll hold off on investigating this further. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

This scenario, `cbind`ing a bunch of vectors, is set up perfectly for dumping the information right into a [sparse, column-oriented](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/dgCMatrix-class.html) matrix (`dgCMatrix` class).

Here's a function that will do it:

```
sv.cbind <- function (...) {
    input <- lapply( list(...), as, "dsparseVector" )
    thelength <- unique(sapply(input,length))
    stopifnot( length(thelength)==1 )
    return( sparseMatrix( 
            x=unlist(lapply(input,slot,"x")), 
            i=unlist(lapply(input,slot,"i")), 
            p=c(0,cumsum(sapply(input,function(x){length(x@x)}))),
            dims=c(thelength,length(input))
        ) )
}
```

From a quick test, this looks to be about 10 times faster than coercion + `cBind`:

```
require(microbenchmark)
xx <- lapply( 1:10, function (k) {
            sparseVector( x=rep(1,100), i=sample.int(1e4,100), length=1e4 )
        } )
microbenchmark( do.call( sv.cbind, xx ), do.call( cBind, lapply(xx,as,"sparseMatrix") ) )
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                            expr       min        lq      mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#                           do.call(sv.cbind, xx)  1.398565  1.464517  1.540172  1.49487  1.55911  3.455421   100  a 
#  do.call(cBind, lapply(xx, as, "sparseMatrix")) 16.037890 16.356268 16.956326 16.59854 17.49956 20.256253   100   b
```

Comment: `cbind` end up calling the S4 method. See [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/75515d1ab51638f20405d8e6925285a85342b7d8/src/main/bind.c#L1107-L1112). Thus, [this code](https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/900993ec067e1c21274ca194fa8bb074673e31df/R/bind2.R#L246-L265) will be called and there may be checks there which you do not perform. I am not sure if it matters but it may.

Comment: @petrelharp. Brilliant, the most intuitive solution for a fast operation. All the coding I didn't want to do and done well.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Josh O'Brien for suggesting a solution: create 3 lists, then create sparseMatrix.
I include the code for this here:

```
vectorList2Matrix<-function(vectorList){
 nzCount<-lapply(vectorList, function(x) length(x@j));
 nz<-sum(do.call(rbind,nzCount));
 r<-vector(mode="integer",length=nz);
 c<-vector(mode="integer",length=nz);
 v<-vector(mode="integer",length=nz);
 ind<-1;
 for(i in 1:length(vectorList)){
    ln<-length(vectorList[[i]]@i);
    if(ln>0){
     r[ind:(ind+ln-1)]<-i;
     c[ind:(ind+ln-1)]<-vectorList[[i]]@j+1
     v[ind:(ind+ln-1)]<-vectorList[[i]]@x
     ind<-ind+ln;
    }
 }
 return (sparseMatrix(i=r,j=c,x=v));
}
```

Comment: helped me a lot! However, I combine vectors of same size, so my solution contains a bit less code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32525837/1075993