# R Turning a list into a matrix when the list contains objects of "different size"

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, structure

I've seen a couple of questions about turning matrices into lists (not really clear why you would want that) but the reverse operation I've been unable to find.

Basically, following

```
# ind.dum = data frame with 29 observations and 2635 variables
for (i in 1:ncol(ind.dum))
tmp[[i]]<-which(rollapply(ind.dum[,i],4,identical,c(1,0,0,0),by.column=T))
```

I got a list of 2635 objects, most of which contain 1 value, bust some up to 7. I'd need to convert this to a matrix with 2635 rows and as many columns as necessary to fit every value in a separate cells (with 0 values for the rest).

I tried all the **coerce** measures I know (`as.data.frame`, `as.matrix` ...) and also the option to define a new matrix with the maximum dimensions but nothing works.

```
m<-matrix(0,nrow=2635,ncol=7)
tmp_m<-structure(tmp,dim=dim(m))
Error in structure(tmp,dim=dim(m))dims [product 18445] do not match the length of object [2635]
```

I'm sure there's a quick fix for this so I'm hoping someone can help me with it. Btw, my values in the tmp list's objects are numeric, although some are "integer(0)" , i.e. when the pattern c(1,0,0,0) was not found in the columns of the original ind.dum matrix.

Not sure if there is a way to use `unlist` without losing the information about which values belong originally to the same row...

**Desired Output**
A matrix or dataframe with 2635 rows and 7 columns and looking like this

```
12 0 0 0 0 0 0
8 14 0 0 0 0 0 
0  0 0 0 0 0 0 
1  4 8 12 0 0 0 
...
```

The values basically refer to years in which a specific pattern started. I need to be able to be able to use that information to tie this problem to an earlier problem described before (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543230/finding-repeat-patterns-in-columns-of-matrix-and-tie-findings-to-another-matrix)).

Comment: Wondering if this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843700/creating-sparse-matrix-from-a-list-of-sparse-vectors can help get you part of the way. For the list entries fewer values than 7, what are you using to know which value belongs in which resultant column?

Comment: Hi, not sure what a sparse matrix exactly is but I'll check whether the suggested code is useful. The location of values in columns is not that important. I'll update my question with desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for example:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(ll,
               function(x)
                 if(length(x)==1)c(x,rep(0,6))
               else x))
```

Comment: Wow this solves 90% of the problem. What remains is that if there are for instance two (or more) values: tmp[[1540]] is 4  18, then those values get repeated in the matrix-like structure..., so you get 4  18  4  18 4  18  4 - Just updated your suggestion with the small tweak so now it's perfect. Thanks a lot @agstudy

Comment: I just noticed another minor problem with the solution. Rows that initially have value "integer(0)" dissapear completely so the final output only has 2433 rows rather than the desired 2635.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fast alternative that does what it sounds like you are describing:

First, sample data always helps:

```
LL <- list(1:3, numeric(0), c(1:3,1), 1:7)
LL
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# numeric(0)
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 2 3 1
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Second, we'll make use of a little trick referred to as matrix indexing to fill an empty matrix with the values from your list.

```
## We need to know how many columns are needed for each list item
Ncol <- vapply(LL, length, 1L)

## M is our empty matrix, pre-filled with zeroes
M <- matrix(0, nrow = length(LL), ncol = max(Ncol))

## IJ is the row/column combination where values need to be inserted
IJ <- cbind(rep(seq_along(Ncol), times = Ncol), sequence(Ncol)) 

## Extract and insert!
M[IJ] <- unlist(LL, use.names = FALSE)

## View the result
M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    1    2    3    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    1    2    3    1    0    0    0
# [4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure this works fine as well and the syntax is easier to understand for a novice like me. Will surely try and use this next time I face a list-> df conversion :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution.

Not sure if it is good enough or there's any bug.

```
LL <- list(1:3, numeric(0), c(1:3, 1), 1:7)

with(data.frame(m <- plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(LL, matrix, nrow = 1))), replace(m, is.na(m), 0))
```

Comment: Paste if when you know (at least don't think) there isn't a bug?