# Combine different rowcells from a data.table or data.frame based on simple condition

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, data.table, apply

I have a data.frame that looks like this

```
dput(repex) = structure(list(cat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("x", 
"y", "z"), class = "factor"), year = c(1980, 1980, 1982, 1982, 
1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1993, 1981, 1981, 1983, 1990, 1996, 1996, 
1996, 1996, 1999, 2002, 1994), org = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 
3L, 9L), .Label = c("709340", "a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "j", "k", 
"e", "h", "m"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("cat", "year", 
"org"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a new object (ideally a data.table or data.frame) in which the elements of `org` are grouped horizontally behind a specific `cat, year` combination

I tried to run the following:

```
repex <- data.table(repex)
setkey(repex,cat,year)
repex[, list(org), by="cat,year"]  #OR
repex[, paste(org,sep="_"), by="cat,year"] # OR
with(repex, tapply(org,paste(cat,year,sep="_"),paste))
```

The first two data.table options merely copy the entire data.table and the tapply option (applied to repex as either data.table or data.frame) works for a small dataset but creates a list object which is not really convenient as I would need to add the output to another data.frame that is based on the cat_year combination... Additionally for a long dataset (nrow > 100,000) it takes forever, especially as in some cases it needs to paste > 100 org-variants.

My desired output would be a data.table that looks something like this

```
x 1980 a b
x 1982 a c # org would ideally be rearranged
x 1990 d
x 1991 f j k 
...
y 1996 c e h m
...
z 2002 b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your actual problems is using the incorrect arguments to `paste`. You are looking for `collapse`, not `sep`. Another problem is using "data.table" syntax incorrectly.

---

#### Update

Considering the comments to this answer, I would suggest something like this instead:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
DT <- as.data.table(repex)

setkey(DT, cat, year, org) ## Sorts everything

## Creates a column "var" with the sequence of values ("V1", "V2", and so on)
DT[, var := paste("V", sequence(.N), sep = ""), by = list(cat, year)]
head(DT)
#    cat year org var
# 1:   x 1980   a  V1
# 2:   x 1980   b  V2
# 3:   x 1982   a  V1
# 4:   x 1982   c  V2
# 5:   x 1990   d  V1
# 6:   x 1991   f  V1
```

Converts that to a "wide" format:

```
dcast.data.table(DT, cat + year ~ var, value.var="org")
#     cat year V1 V2 V3 V4
#  1:   x 1980  a  b NA NA
#  2:   x 1982  a  c NA NA
#  3:   x 1990  d NA NA NA
#  4:   x 1991  f  j  k NA
#  5:   x 1993  e NA NA NA
#  6:   y 1981  a  b NA NA
#  7:   y 1983  d NA NA NA
#  8:   y 1990  b NA NA NA
#  9:   y 1996  c  e  h  m
# 10:   z 1994  e NA NA NA
# 11:   z 1999  h NA NA NA
# 12:   z 2002  b NA NA NA
```

---

#### Original answer

This is a pretty straightforward `aggregate` problem:

```
aggregate(org ~ cat + year, repex, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = " "))
#    cat year     org
# 1    x 1980     a b
# 2    y 1981     a b
# 3    x 1982     a c
# 4    y 1983       d
# 5    x 1990       d
# 6    y 1990       b
# 7    x 1991   f j k
# 8    x 1993       e
# 9    z 1994       e
# 10   y 1996 c e h m
# 11   z 1999       h
# 12   z 2002       b
```

---

A "data.table" approach:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(repex)
DT[, list(org = paste(sort(org), collapse = " ")), by = list(cat, year)]
```

And, to round things out, a "dplyr" approach:

```
library(dplyr)
repex %.% group_by(cat, year) %.% summarise(org = paste(sort(org), collapse = " "))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your useful replies. I managed to design a way less elegant solution myself in the meanwhile. So I'll be using your aggregate or data.table one (the dplyr syntax is too scary :). However, is there a way of changing the `collapse` command so that the different `org` end up in different matrix cells? So for x 1980 org1 would be a and org2 (another column) would be b ...

Comment: @Arun, I checked with the example dataset and this creates a solution that is actually better than the one I had in mind as it orders the `org` in separate columns which is fantastic for later search purposes. Unfortunately, in my dataset with > 14,500 different org and > 40,000 different `cat` (short for categories) it creates data-handling problems as the resulting object  > 2 GB. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @Arun I guess you are right. In the solution I proposed myself  I avoid this. In my dataset the maximum width necessary is 464 (i.e. 464 organisations are active in the same category in a specific year). I can draw those 464 neatly into different cells and create a lot less NAs than in the `dcast` format. Nonetheless, a private column for each organization would make specific counts and forms of network analysis (e.g. how do activities of specific `org` in specific `cat` in year "t" influence other `org` in similar `cat` in year "t+1") easier to visualise! Thanks for your solution!!!

Comment: Thanks both for your great suggestions. @Arun the total number of unique values is over 33,000 but per row there are no more than 464. @ AnandaMahto 's solution basically combines your suggestion with a less memory-intense approach. It's perfect!

Comment: I just ran it on my entire dataset and it works a lot faster than the solution I proposed. The only downside is that the order of the columns in `dcast` is inconvenient as it goes V1 V100 V101...

Comment: @simon_icl, that should be an easy fix since you now have a `data.table`. You can easily use `setcolorder`. Try `setcolorder(out, c("org", "cat", grep("^V", names(out), value=TRUE)[order(nchar(grep("^V", names(out), value = TRUE)))]))` (assuming your final `data.table` is called "out"). Untested, of course :-)

Comment: Haha I love what you describe as a simple command. Maybe in 10 years that would be simple for me as well! But it does not work because the variable "org" is not part of the DT created by `dcast.data.table` (at least that's my best guess for why it might not work. Error message states: "names in neworder not found in x: org - but don't worry about it, I can easily the moveme function to get the 10 first rows in place, that's what matters anyway!

Answer (score 0):

@Anandaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,

Here's my inelegant way of solving the problem myself. I am sure there is an easier way that takes your advice but just thought I'd share as well.

Step 1: Paste all the `org` into a list

```
tmp1 <- with(repex, tapply(org,paste(cat,year,sep="_"), paste))
```

Step 2: Find the longest length of the list (very inelegantly)

```
x<-as.vector(NA)
for (i in 1:length(fy_ids)) {
  x[i] <- length(fy_ids[[i]])
  }
max(x)
```

Step 3: Using the maximum for x, construct a data.frame in which each organization occurs in a new cell (with special thanks to @agstudy for a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616292/r-turning-a-list-into-a-matrix-when-the-list-contains-objects-of-different-size)

```
tmp <- do.call(rbind,lapply(tmp1,
               function(y)
                 if(length(y)>0)c(y,rep(NA, max(x)-length(y)))
                             else c(y,rep(NA,max(x)))))
```

Step 4: Turn `tmp` into a data.frame

`tmp <- data.frame(tmp)`

I know it's pretty cumbersome but it has the advantage of making search for specific `org` a lot easier as each `org` appears in a different cell.

Comment: I wouldn't have downvoted this because it does attempt to answer the question (+1) even though it's presented more as a long comment. However, it's not an efficient approach. I've added an alternative to agstudy's answer at your other question that is more efficient (even if it may require more setup time with the code). Oh, and the name's Anand***a*** :-)

Comment: Thanks @AnandaMahto for your great answer and for bearing with me while I altered my initial question. I appreciate your "no downvote" action as well :).